# How to predict the next item based on the list

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, ibm-watson

I am carrying out a task which I need to know which is the next element based on a list.

Real example:
I have a list of triangles with BLUE and PINK colors of different sizes and these sizes can be alternated.

What I need is to predict what the color of the next triangle will be based on the current list passed. (the size would be great).

I tried to search for Watson AI, TensorFlow and etc. but I couldn't find anything.

I am new to this area and I am looking for that learning.

Could someone indicate something or a set of things that I can use to get closer to that result?

If possible send me an example code or something like that..

Answer (score 0):

If the shapes and colours are random, then it's just guesswork, and a random number generator is probably the best you are going to get.

If there is a limited set, like a pack of cards, then you could use probabilities to guess what is next.

If there is an unlimited set and always a defined pattern where the next colour can be predicted, then you might be able to use a machine learning model. To get started just explore the web and find a getting started with machine learning tutorial. They will be python biased, and scikit-learn is probably all you need.